# I dreamt another dream?

Tags: vocabulary

Would you tell me when you say this sentence or what does it mean?

> I dreamt another dream.

Many thanks.

Comment: *Dreamt* is one of the past tense form of the verb *to dream*. The form that is used more often these days is *dreamed*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the sense "next dream, a dream that follows some previous dream":

> I woke in the middle of the night, because I had a nightmare. I drank some tea and read ELL Stack Exchange a little. Then I went to bed and **dreamt another dream**.. it turned out to be the same nightmare with the same scenario.

In the sense "a dream that is different from some other dream":

> Hi, CopperKettle!
>   Hi, Nima! Did you have the same nightmare again today?
>   No, this time I **dreamt another dream**, it was very peaceful.

P.S. You can always look up [definitions in the dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/another) and dream up examples by yourself, then ask us whether they are okay.

P.P.S. You [can "dream" a dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_a_Little_Dream_of_Me), but the more frequent usage is to "have" a dream. [Here's an Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20had%20a%20dream%2C%20I%20dreamt%20a%20dream%2C%20I%20dreamed%20a%20dream&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20had%20a%20dream%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20dreamt%20a%20dream%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20dreamed%20a%20dream%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

P.P.P.S. "[Having a dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Have_a_Dream)" is not always equal in meaning with "dreaming a dream".

Comment: Would it be fair to say the average person would say "had another dream"?

Comment: Probably yes, @Catija, I'm not a native speaker. (0: You can post your answer and point this out. Does "dreamt another dream" look strange to you as a native speaker?

Comment: I think your answer is great. It addresses the question and I like that you noted there are two interpretations of "another", which I wouldn't have thought of. As an American, I can only say that it's perfectly intelligible and works well in writing but my lazy American mouth would simplify to *had another dream* because the specifics of it being dreamt are implied.

Comment: @Catija - thanks for the comment! "Had a dream" is likely to be the more frequent usage, so nothing lazy here. (0:

Comment: You might look up *dream**ed*** another dream, since the -ed ending was/is preferred by some folks. I have no idea what the results might be. EDIT: Also, the song from *Les Miserables* is *[I dreamed a dream](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzNVmZfNoa8)*.

Comment: @δοῦλος - thanks for the comment! It is indeed attested, and even in slightly higher numbers.

Comment: Dreamed a dream is more common (I think) because Americans use it. Dreamt is not actually a word used in the US and my computer marks it as misspelled.

Comment: I grew up in the US using *dreamt* and switched over to *dreamed* later.  So if it is no longer in the US it's pretty recent.  I'm not that old!  :)  Mac TextEdit doesn't complain at *dreamt* and corrected *dreamted* to *dreamed*.  I say *dreamt* is still in use but *dreamed* is more common.  Finally "dream a little dream for me" seems much more poetic than "have a little dream for me".

Comment: @BobRodes It's Firefox (OSX) that doesn't like dreamt, though the FF dictionary is noticeably lacking at some times... I also keep wanting to ad a **p** to the word (dreampt). I've been humming "Dream a little dream for me" off and on since I first saw this question.

Comment: As you could see, even some native speakers have some controversial issues as to my question, so I think it is right that I should raised my question.\

Comment: @nima Me too.  :)